# In django how can i create a model instance from a string value?

Tags: django

All,

I have strings that represent my model and fields, like this

```
modelNameStr = 'MyModel'
fieldNameStr = 'modelField'
```

My model looks like this;

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    modelField = ForeignKey( ForeignModel )
    ...
```

What i want to do is create an instance of **MyModel** using the string variables, something like

```
model_instance = modelNameStr.objects.filter(fieldNameStr=ForeignModelInstance)
```

How can i do this?

Gath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
model_instance = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=u'someapp', model=modelNameStr).model_class()(**{fieldNameStr: ForeignModelInstance})
```

Phew! Try saying *that* five times fast! But make sure you use the appropriate value for `app_label`.

Comment: How can we use the filter with ContentType?

Answer (score 3):

Retrieving the model class you can use the `get_model` function from Django. Though you have to use a string like `my_app.MyModel` where 'my_app' is your django app which includes the model. Filtering field values can be achieved via a dict. Here an example:

```
from django.db.models import get_model

modelNameStr = 'my_app.MyModel'
fieldNameStr = 'modelField'

ModelClass = get_model(*model_class.split('.'))
filters = {fieldNameStr: ForeignModelInstance}

model_instance = ModelClass.objects.filter(**filters)
```