# How to store a reference to model type in another model instance

Tags: django, model, reference, instance, meta

So this is a little exercise in the meta meta.. I want to be able to store model reference as a row in a table associated with another model. Something like this:

```
class Widget(models.Model):
  related = models.Model() # data model associated with this widget
  identifier = models.CharField(max_length=500) # human-friendly descriptor
```

This doesn't validate.. I've found an [acceptable workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659377/in-django-how-can-i-create-a-model-instance-from-a-string-value), but I'm wondering if there's a more proper/graceful way of doing this.

Thanks, django wizards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) is what you need.  Have you looked at it?

Comment: I think so. To be honest, having read the answers here and the related documentation sent me back to the drawing board -- but that's a good thing, right?
 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hold the actual model of another object, you can simply use a foreignkey to a [content type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
class Widget(models.Model):
    related = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=500) # human-friendly descriptor
```